# How to record memory usage?

Tags: ram, memory-usage, memory-test

I need a program or tool to record the memory usage ( RAM ) and save it to a file so i can take the file and open it. so i can see the result and make the comparison with other by myself.

Comment: You get the RAM usage with the command `free`. If you want to log the RAM usage, you can make a script that redirects the output of `free` to a file at regular intervals, for example every 5 seconds (maybe together the the current time).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following command in bash like so:

```
for i in `seq 0 60`; do
  echo `cat /proc/meminfo | grep Active: | sed 's/Active: //g'` >> usage.txt
  sleep 1m
done
```

This command will record the current memory use to a file named 'usage.txt' every minute for the duration of 1 hour.

If you wish, you can change the `usage.txt` part of the command to save under a different name. You can also change the `sleep 1m` command to alter the time between each entry and the '60' in the `seq` section at the top to change the number of entries to be recorded.

When you have finished making your entries, you will have a text file of entries that can be imported into a spreadsheet for easy comparison.

EDIT:
If you wish to also record the total memory with each entry, you can use the following commands:

```
for i in `seq 0 60`; do
  echo `cat /proc/meminfo | grep Active: | sed 's/Active: //g'`/`cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemTotal: | sed 's/MemTotal: //g'` >> usage.txt
  sleep 1m
done
```

These commands will instead record entries in the form of `<active>/<total>`

Comment: thanks a lot your answer is very useful and simple and i still want to record the total memory too so i will appreciate if you can rewrite the code above to make it record the MemTotal and Active at the same time

Comment: I will assume that you want it to record one entry per line in the form `<active>/<total>`

Comment: This was useful for me too.  In my case, I needed continual monitoring for a long-running application, so I just put this into an infinite loop (`while true; do ...`), then when the application finishes, I just kill the process.

Answer (score 1):

[sysstat](https://github.com/sysstat/sysstat) does exactly that -- runs on a cron schedule and records various system metrics (CPU, RAM, block device usage and so on). Basically you `apt-get install sysstat` and forget about it. By default it keeps the metrics for the last month.

Later when need to disgnose an issue, you can use its CLI, [sar](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sar), to browser the data or an 3rd party GUI, [ksar](https://github.com/vlsi/ksar) for visualisation.